# New Line in Rich Text Content Control of Word open xml

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a Word document that has a `Rich text Content Control`.

I want to add text with new line.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument theDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docName, true))
 {
   MainDocumentPart mainPart = theDoc.MainDocumentPart;
   foreach (SdtElement sdt in mainPart.Document.Descendants<SdtElement>())
     {
        SdtAlias alias = sdt.Descendants<SdtAlias>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (alias != null)
          {
            string sdtTitle = alias.Val.Value;
            var t = sdt.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault();
             if (sdtTitle == "Body")
               {
                 t.Text = "Welcome to Yazd With its winding lanes, forest of badgirs,\r\n mud-brick houses and delightful places to stay, Yazd is a 'don't miss' destination. On a flat plain ringed by mountains, \r\nthe city is wedged between the northern Dasht-e Kavir and southern Dasht-e Lut and is every inch a city of the desert." }
         }
     }
}
```

I use a text with `\r\n` but don't add new line.

Comment: But the text is added? Is the \r\n just left out? Note that, for one new line, use only `\r` or `\n`, not both (that should give two lines). Are you absolutley certain this is a RichText content control and not plain text? Are you able to type new lines in it if you open the document in Word, as a user?

Comment: Ah, and what does `model-view-controller` have to do with the question?

Comment: @CindyMeister, "\r\n" (Carriage Return and Newline) is the line separator on Windows operating systems. On Unix, Linux, and macOS, for example, the line separator is "\n" (Newline).

Comment: @ThomasBarnekow This information is irrelevant for content added to a Word document, using the Open XML file format. Firstly, ***Word*** does not recognize the combination and secondly, it certainly should not be used in the expectation of generating new lines in an Open XML document. The code in the question will display the characters, as they stand. The code needs to generate Paragraphs and Runs if new lines are required.

Comment: @CindyMeister, I do understand that. I am a contributor to the Open XML SDK and PowerTools for Open XML, and my answer below should support that as well. Word would render each line separator as a single space character (which can be verified by playing around with a w:t element that has one or more line separators in the text). I just reacted to your comment on not using "\r\n" as a line separator. Contrary to what you suggested, "\r\n" does not produce two lines because the combination of those two control characters is the line separator on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Some characters like tabs, new lines, etc. are defined with a special XML element.
For your case, you need `<w:br/>` element so try something like the following:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument theDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docName, true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = theDoc.MainDocumentPart;
    foreach (SdtElement sdt in mainPart.Document.Descendants<SdtElement>())
    {
        SdtAlias alias = sdt.Descendants<SdtAlias>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (alias != null && alias.Val.Value == "Body")
        {
            var run = sdt.Descendants<Run>().FirstOrDefault();
            run.RemoveAllChildren<Text>();

            var text = "Welcome to Yazd With its winding lanes, forest of badgirs,\r\n mud-brick houses and delightful places to stay, Yazd is a 'don't miss' destination. On a flat plain ringed by mountains, \r\nthe city is wedged between the northern Dasht-e Kavir and southern Dasht-e Lut and is every inch a city of the desert.";
            var lines = text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                run.AppendChild(new Text(line));
                run.AppendChild(new Break());
            }

            run.Elements<Break>().Last().Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do want to restrict your function to Rich Text Content Controls, i.e., block-level structured document tags, you would be looking for instances of `SdtBlock`. Using `SdtElement`, you would also find inline-level (`SdtRun`), row-level (`SdtRow`), and cell-level (`SdtCell`) structured document tags, because `SdtBlock`, `SdtRun`, `SdtRow`, and `SdtCell` are subclasses of `SdtElement`.

The following is a straightforward implementation that assumes the Rich Text Content Control is supposed to contain only the multi-line text. It trims the lines because the sample text contains what looks like extraneous spaces.

```cs
public void AddMultiLineTextToRichTextContentControlsUsingRuns()
{
    // Produce the list of lines from the text separated by "\r\n"
    // in the question, trimming leading and trailing whitespace.
    const string text = "Welcome to Yazd With its winding lanes, forest of badgirs,\r\n mud-brick houses and delightful places to stay, Yazd is a 'don't miss' destination. On a flat plain ringed by mountains, \r\nthe city is wedged between the northern Dasht-e Kavir and southern Dasht-e Lut and is every inch a city of the desert.";
    string[] separator = { "\r\n" };

    List<string> lines = text
        .Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None)
        .Select(line => line.Trim())
        .ToList();

    // Get the w:document element.
    const string path = @"path\to\your\document.docx";
    using WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true);
    Document document = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document;

    // Get all Rich Text (i.e., block) w:sdt elements having a w:alias
    // descendant with w:val="Body".
    IEnumerable<SdtBlock> sdts = document
        .Descendants<SdtBlock>()
        .Where(sdt => sdt.Descendants<SdtAlias>().Any(alias => alias.Val == "Body"));

    foreach (SdtBlock sdt in sdts)
    {
        // Create one w:r element per line, prepending a w:br to the
        // second and following runs.
        IEnumerable<Run> runs = lines
            .Select((line, index) =>
                index == 0
                    ? new Run(new Text(line))
                    : new Run(new Break(), new Text(line)));

        // Create or replace the w:sdtContent element with one that has
        // a single w:p with one or more w:r children.
        sdt.SdtContentBlock = new SdtContentBlock(new Paragraph(runs));
    }
}
```